# How to call non-transactional methods from a Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a method that is Transactional and I have a private method that is non-transactional that does some db update.

I need to call this private method from the transactional method but in case of exception the updates from non-transactional are also rolled back.

How can I made the non transactional method to commit the update from private method because it is called from transactional method and in case of exception its changes are also rolled back

```
@Transactional
public Result createTransaction(){
    try{
         //do someting
      }Catch (Exception e){
         markAsFailed();
         throw new CtxException("customer.notfound");
       }
}


 private void markAsFailed(){
        //do db update
       }
```

Comment: sorry, so your question is?

Comment: looks like while doing the ctrl+z I removed the question, so I added it back

Comment: markAsFailed should be a transactional method, in another bean, using REQUIRES_NEW propagation. Otherwise, everything it does is part of the transaction started by createTransaction().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just putting up  the answer in case if someone needs, the important point to note is the Transactional Method that needs to be called from a non Transactional method should be in separate spring bean as mentioned by   [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) because spring works with proxies to achieve this behaviour and  will have to define the method in another class so that spring should be able to trigger the transactions. Once you are inside a class you will not go through the proxy again

Answer (score 1):

Transactional Method that needs to be called from a non Transactional method should be in separate spring bean